# Need to make synchronous REST calls in WP8 using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, rest, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I've looked at some of the answers for similar questions and can't seem to find something that is applicable to what I'm doing.  I need to make a few synchronous requests using HttpWebRequest (some using each verb, GET/PUT/POST/DELETE) and can't seem to get it to work.  The example below works great when I manually use a 'refresh' button that I have in the design (works for any verb specified), but when I uncomment the section in 'b_send_Click' it doesn't work.  What I'm looking for is a wrapper method that will encapsulate the REST client (the way 'b_send_Click' does in this example) and then take some action when the call is complete (the commented section in 'b_send_Click' as an example).  Any ideas?  By the way, this works well as a wrapper for async REST calls but I can't get the sync working...

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;

namespace WP8Rest
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // global variables
        public static string url = "http://mywebsite.com/API/some_api";
        public static string request_body = "";
        public static HttpWebRequest client = null;
        public static HttpWebResponse response = null;
        public static string server_response = "";
        public static bool request_done = false;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void b_send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            rest_request(sender, e);

            /*
            while (!request_done)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            if (response != null)
            {
                l_status_code.Text = response.StatusCode.ToString();
                l_status_description.Text = response.StatusDescription.ToString();
                l_response.Text = server_response;
            }
            else
            {
                l_status_code.Text = "0";
                l_status_description.Text = "Unable to complete request...";
                l_response.Text = "Unable to complete request...";
            }
             */
        }

        private void rest_request(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            request_done = false;
            server_response = "";
            request_body = tb_reqbody.Text;
            client = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            client.Method = tb_verb.Text;
            client.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

            switch (tb_verb.Text)
            {
                case "GET":
                    client.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), client);
                    break;

                case "PUT":
                    client.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), client);
                    client.ContentType = "application/json";
                    break;

                case "POST":
                    client.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), client);
                    client.ContentType = "application/json";
                    break;

                case "DELETE":
                    client.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), client);
                    client.ContentType = "application/json";
                    break;

                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("Use GET, PUT, POST, or DELETE.");
                    return;
            }

            l_response.Text = "Request sent...";
            return;
        }

        private static void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult async_result)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)async_result.AsyncState;
            Stream request_body_stream = request.EndGetRequestStream(async_result);
            byte[] request_body_bytearray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request_body);
            request_body_stream.Write(request_body_bytearray, 0, request_body.Length);
            request_body_stream.Close();
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
        }

        private static void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult async_result)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)async_result.AsyncState;
            response = (HttpWebResponse)client.EndGetResponse(async_result);
            Stream response_body_stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader stream_reader = new StreamReader(response_body_stream);
            server_response = stream_reader.ReadToEnd();            
            response_body_stream .Close();
            stream_reader.Close();
            response.Close();
            request_done = true;
        }

        private void b_refresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (response != null)
            {
                l_response.Text = server_response;
                l_status_code.Text = response.StatusCode.ToString();
                l_status_description.Text = response.StatusDescription.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                l_response.Text = "No response...";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Per @Industry86 I was able to get Microsoft.Net.Http installed.  Changed code to:

```
private async void b_send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    l_response.Text = myMethod();
}

async Task<string> myMethod()
{
    string address = "http://dev.getcube.com:65533/rest.svc/API/mirror";
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(address);
    string responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return responseText;
}
```

Problem now is that it won't compile - "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'string'.  I changed the line in b_send_Click to `l_response.Text = (myMethod()).Result;` (not sure if this is correct or not) and when I click the 'b_send' button, it turns orange and the server never sees the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a new answer to focus on your code changes.

put an `await` in front of your async method call:

```
private async void b_send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    l_response.Text = await myMethod();
}
```

when you use `.Result`, it halts the process until the result returns, thereby halting UI and everything else. Here is an SO answer detailing out the problems with this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13703845/311393

Quick lesson: with a void return value, an async method will "fire-and-forget" and never expect a return. With a `Task` or `Task<T>` return value, an async method called will halt the calling method until it's completed.

Thus `b_send_Click` will fire off a thread to do whatever. When it calls `myMethod()`, which is a Task, with the appropriate `await` keyword, it will stop in a synchronous fashion and wait till it's completed whatever it's doing.

And `myMethod()` has multiple async method calls but those have await's on them as well, so the thread will wait for those to complete synchronously as well.

Then it returns back to your text field and the UI, I assume in WP8, listens to changes to it's text field asynchronously.

Comment: HttpClient + your answer did the trick.  I'll see if I can mod from here to make it fit my needs.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would use the HTTPClient that exists in Windows 8 (it's pretty awesome) and currently possibly still in beta for WP8 (https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) if not fully released already. The syntax is much smaller and simpler.
Or use RestSharp (http://restsharp.org/) but the async/await stuff isn't as robust. RestSharp is really good at serialization though.

that said, you also need to learn how Async operations occur. You are calling an Asynchronous operation and moving on without an "await". Therefore:

```
l_response.Text = server_response;
```

will not get set because, without the Thread.Sleep(100), the code will have fired off the async call and move on and server_response will still be *null* by the time it gets to that part.

if you want to want to wait for the return of that call, you need to use an "await" command and include the async signifier in the method declaration and return a Task (where object can be whatever you're intending to return). Example using HttpClient:

```
async Task<string> myMethod()
{
    string address = "http://mywebsite.com/API/some_api";
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(address);
    string responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return responseText;
}
```

and the resulting string "responseText" will have the JSON content to parse. Of course, if you're looking for a stream, its there too.

And you also have to remember that this method itself will require an await from the UI thread and the declaration will be required to be async:

```
private async void b_send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    someTextBox.Text = myMethod();
}
```

and event handlers should typically be the only async methods that return *void*.

Comment: Microsoft.Net.Http is unfortunately not on NuGet yet for WP8 :-/  How would you change the code above?  Cheers

Comment: I just created a new WP8 app, used the install command provided in the link I provided you to get that library from Nuget, took a method I have from a Windows 8 app I'm building where I make a PostAsync (copy/pasted I might add from a Windows 8 app to this Windows Phone 8 app) and returned valid json.
Pretty sure it's on Nuget right now. And pretty sure it works like a charm.
If you're looking to use your existing code, I'm not familiar with that library so I couldn't answer it.

Comment: Used the 'Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Http -Pre' command and it failed.  Could not install package 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.0.19'. You are trying to install this package into a project that 
targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that 
framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: @haxor make sure nuget itself is up to date before trying to install the -Pre version.

Comment: Thanks @Pedro, I just reinstalled from http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c and had the same error.

Comment: Thanks Industry86.  The async-await model is only starting to make sense to me.  Would you be willing to recommend the code changes in the code I supplied above?

Comment: To @Pedro's comment, as a comparison, I have Package Manager Console Host Version 2.5.40416.9020. Maybe that is why I could get it and you could not.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking @haxor. Are you saying you made changes and want my opinion or you'd like me to provide an example more fitting your code?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  I was asking for an example more fitting to the code I supplied above.

Comment: Honestly, it appears that library doesn't support async/await very well (thus my push for HttpClient). However, here is a question from someone farther along but trying to understand the solution. The answer appears to have a link to workable code.
(http://stackoverflow.com/q/13733749/311393)
Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: @Industry86 it (for who knows whatever reason) allowed me to install Microsoft.Net.Http.  I implemented your example, see modification above.  Thanks